# query pulls from textbox and sets column name from combo box

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, combobox

I am coding in vb on visual studio 2012 and I need to create a query that pulls table data into a datagriddview. I have a textbox for user input and a combobox to set what the column name. Sort of like, "SELECT * FROM TITLES WHERE COMBOBOX LIKE TEXTBOX". I apologize if this question is old ground for you but I looked everywhere and couldn't find what I was looking for. Also I am a total newb so please speak slowly and in small words. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: you just about have it - **provided** this is coming from a DB and these controls are for a user search.  The `ComboBox.Text` should indicate the column/field name, and `TextBox.Text` the search term.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your `SQL` to be:

```
"SELECT * FROM TITLES WHERE " & ComboBox1.Text & " LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"
```

Comment: I tried this and am getting an "end of statement expected" error     here is my code~                   sql = "SELECT * FROM TITLES WHERE " & ComboBox1.SelectedText " LIKE '%" & txtProd.Text & "%'"

Comment: @McRhea answer updated (added `&`), I think I was deleted while formatting the code.

Answer (score 1):

Deja Vu's answer should be ok. You may take it a step further, and try using a parameter instead of building the sql string directly from users' direct input, thus avoiding SQL Injection (which is a security risk):

```
Dim Sql As String = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE " & ComboBox1.Text & " LIKE '%?%' "
Dim p As New OleDb.OleDbParameter : p.Value = Textbox1.text 
Dim OleDBCommand As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(Sql, Connection)
OleDBCommand.Parameters.Add(p)
Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(OleDBCommand)
Dim DT As New DataTable
da.Fill(DT)
```

(Note: I'm assuming this is an Application and users must choose an item from the combobox, and they cannot change the content of the combobox.)